# Pills in version 3.0.3 won't work

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
            <li class="active"><a href="#details" data-toggle="pill">Details</a></li>
            <li><a href="#logs" data-toggle="pill">Logs</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-10">
        <div class="pill-content">
            <div class="pill-pane active" id="details">
                pill details
            </div>
            <div class="pill-pane" id="logs">
                pill logs
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

It works on 3.0.0 but on 3.0.3 won't work and I have no idea what's wrong.
Well, I was trying to find changes in documentation but there's nothing at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this..

```
 <div class="pill-content">
            <div class="pill-pane active" id="details">
                pill details
            </div>
            <div class="pill-pane" id="logs">
                pill logs
            </div>
    </div>
```

To this..

```
<div class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane active" id="details">
        pill details
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="logs">
        pill logs
    </div>
</div>
```

Demo: http://bootply.com/103792

Comment: I don't know. Perhaps to minimize the `tabs.js` component.

Comment: I have to follow github changes, because documentation hasn't got too much info about changes.

Comment: bs 3.0.3 is an official release. This should be or documented or related as a bug.